# Biholomorphic maps from unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $f$ be biholomorphic map from the unit disc onto some $D \subset \overline{\mathbb{C}}$ (considered as a Riemann sphere, so it is holomorphic) with
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}+c_1z+c_2z^2+\cdots$$
What does inequality
$$\sum n |c_n|^2 \leq 1$$
mean geometrically?

Comment: There is something wrong with your question. Your function is not holomorphic on the unit disc.

Comment: We consider it as a Riemann sphere, so it is holomorphic map, not function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement of $D$ is a compact subset of the plane. Its area can be computed in terms of $f$, using Green's formula. This computation yields
$$\text{area of $\mathbb C\setminus D$} =   \pi-\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty n|c_n|^2$$
Therefore, the inequality $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n|c_n|^2 \le 1$  expresses the  fact that area cannot be negative. This is why the result is known as the [Area Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_theorem_%28conformal_mapping%29); the wiki has the detailed computation to which I alluded above.